# Disabled zoom and pan in ArcGIS desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, extents

I have an MXD that someone else has created. They have put some sort of lock on the extent that stops me from zooming and panning. I can't for the life of me work out how to turn it off.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They probably set it to a fixed extent. If you right click the data frame, go to properties, and under the "Data Frame" tab you can set the extent to "Automatic" which should allow you to move things around.

[image]