# Pan and Zoom toolbar greyed out on ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, toolbar

Pan and Zoom toolbar greyed out on ArcGIS Desktop.

[image]

I recently installed ArcGIS 10.4. 
I have checked the data frame properties and the Extent is set to Automatic. 
I am using the data view not layout view. 
Normally I could pan and zoom in and out with ArcGIS 10.3 on this view but now I can't select these options.

Can anyone advise me how to activate this toolbar again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the layout toolbar it will be disabled while in Data View.  To enable it go into Layout View (View (menu)>Layout View).

Comment: Normally I could pan and zoom in and out with ArcGIS 10.3 on Data View but now I can't select these options. I think something needs to be enabled somewhere but not sure what.

Comment: The Layout toolbar is not meant for pan/zooming in the Data View, to turn on the pan/zoom toolbar for the Data View select Customize menu>Toolbars>Tools

Comment: Sorry for the delay. New to using Stack Exchange. Thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

If you go to the data frame in your table of contents, right click and select properties, Go to Data Frame tab and look at Extent. I am assuming that this map is set up as a 'Fixed Extent' which will not allow you to zoom.

Also...See [Disabled zoom and pan in ArcGIS desktop](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/97615/disabled-zoom-and-pan-in-arcgis-desktop)

Comment: I have checked this and the data frame extent is set to automatic. I am using the data view not layout view. Normally I could pan and zoom in and out with ArcGIS 10.3 on this view but now I can't select these options.

Answer (score 1):

I had the wrong toolbar enabled for my View or order to pan and zoom.

For Data View "Tools" needs to be enabled
Customize menu>Toolbars>Tools

For Layout View "Layout" needs to be enabled.
Customize menu>Toolbars>Layout